# img src external link not showing

Tags: html, image, web

html

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/gIDHwjm.jpg">
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

i test on 5 browser

microsoft edge ------ not showing

firefox nightly ------ not showing

chrome ------ **showing**

Vivaldi ------ not showing

Brave ------ **showing**

error on microsoft edge

[image]

I want img src external link showing on every browser

how can i fix it??

Comment: can't reproduce, for me works fine

Comment: Just turned your code into a runnable snippet. The image shows fine for me in Edge, Chrome and Firefox. No errors.

Comment: Open your Console (Right Click + Inspect Element) to see if whether  the image is broken or not.

Comment: edge Inspect Element looking fine sir but still not show image https://i.imgur.com/d5JWSVj.png

Comment: Maby you did to many Requests to i.imgur reloading your page, and they blocked you now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried hosting the image on your computer and then set the img src to get the image from there.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
  <title>test</title>
  </head>
  <body>

  <img src="images/gIDHwjm.jpg">

  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: internal link is working fine sir but i want external link.. now external link not showing

Comment: Like Pitzas comment, due to too many requests to imgur your requests might have been blocked. Try hosting the image on another server(google drive, drop box e.t.c) and link from there